# AngularJS return value in the scope from an addEventListener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, dom-events

I have an AngularApp in an iframe and I have a controller with this code to get a click event from the iframe container (main window):

```
        $window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {    
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                console.log(e.data.url); // http://<something>
                $scope.widget.pageUrl = e.data.url;
            });
        });

        console.log($scope.widget.pageUrl); // undefined
```

Everything works fine except I cannot get the `$scope.widget.pageUrl` variable filled. It remains undefined outside the `$window.addEventListener`.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

This should also work:

```
$window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        console.log(e.data.url); // http://<something>
        $scope.widget.pageUrl = e.data.url;
        $scope.$apply();
});

console.log($scope.widget.pageUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yaa that's because javascript have function level scoping which means that you need to pass e into the function that you supply to the `$scope.$apply` otherwise this function will not have event object.

doing this should help.

```
$scope.$apply(function(e) {
    console.log(e.data.url);
    $scope.widget.pageUrl = e.data.url;
});
```

I have not tested it though.

Comment: then e.data is undefined

Comment: Can you update the question with the errors you saw earlier it would help people when they are trying to answer to your question.

Comment: there aren't errors, if you do a console.log($scope.widget.pageUrl) outside the addEventListener you get "undefined". [updated answer]